# convert an hex string to a NSData

Tags: iphone, string, uiimage, hex, nsdata

How can I convert a string in hex format to retrieve from it an NSData and after that an UIImage inside of my iPhone app?

I've got a string (str) that contains a value like X'FFD8FFE000104A46....01010000010001000'.

That string is created from a xml file by the method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
     str = [str stringByAppendingString:string];
}
```

How can I get the image back from that string?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea

Comment: Please rephrase. Give examples.

Answer (score 0):

For converting NSData to a NSString, try "initWithData:encoding:"

For converting NSData to an UIImage, try "imageWithData:"

Answer (score 0):

You may find [GTMStringEncoding](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMStringEncoding.m) helpful, from Google Toolbox For Mac.

Answer (score 0):

my sample code , updated!

```
   -(NSData*)toString:(NSString*)uniStr
{
    int len=[uniStr length]/4;
    unichar *oux=alloca(len*sizeof(unichar));
    unichar *p = oux;

    for (int i=0; i<[uniStr length]/4; i++) {


        NSInteger first= i*4;
        NSUInteger a =toInde([uniStr characterAtIndex:first])<<4;//3 3c
        NSUInteger b =toInde([uniStr characterAtIndex:(first+1)]);//2
        NSUInteger c =toInde([uniStr characterAtIndex:(first+2)])<<12 ;//0 68
        NSUInteger d =toInde([uniStr characterAtIndex:(first+3)])<<8;//0

        unichar x = a+b+c+d;//十进制 3c68->683c
        memcpy(p, &x, 2);
        p++;

    }

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:oux length:len*2];
}

int toInde(int x)
{

    char b=0;
    sprintf(&b, "%c",a);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Ewwww a switch statement for that?